# not able to locate keytool on my mac to sign my apk file

Tags: android, macos, keytool

I've used phonegap Build to create my .apk file and i'm trying to sign it.

I understand that I can do this with the following command:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

But when I run this in terminal I get 'command not found' ?

I'm running this on a mac so from what I've read I have the required JDK installed ( I have xcode ) I guess it might be that the PATH is not set correctly to keytool, but I'm unable to find any simple info on resetting this.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I must be missing something very simple as it can not be this difficult to sign the app ?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `cd`'d into the android-sdk/platform-tools directory (where the keytool will [most likely] reside).  The command won't be found if you aren't in the keytool-containing directory.

Comment: Thanks Mike - I could not see keytool in the platform-tools folder but it did run after cd'ing into it. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 13):

This was a nightmare for me, such a seemingly simple task took far too long.

to locate Keytool on a mac

first type this into command prompt:

`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`

it will spit out something like:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home
```

keytool is located in the same directory as `javac`. ie:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

From bin directory you can use the keytool.

I usually use the `APK` tools in `Eclipse` to sign keys but I generated the fingerprint in past and didn't record it. I need keytool to tell me that value...

Hopefully that helps someone else

Answer (score 13):

Just a note i had to add `'./'` in front within the keytool location.

Keytool Location

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/keytool
```

Command run

```
./keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

`keytool` comes with the Java Development Kit (JDK). So look for the directory that contains javac, java and you will find keytool present over there. You can run it directly from that directory or set the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when running on Mac.
Removing the '$' worked for me, and was then prompted to enter the details to create the keystore.

I then had trouble finding the keystore, as I thought it would be within *.android* under my user account, but it was actually saved straight to my user account [cd users/YourUserName]

Hope that helps anyone with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

New location for keytool if you have Android Studio installed is

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).