# Android Google Maps: Obtaining api key

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1, android-maps-v2

I am following this tutorial here:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

On my mac and am not sure how to accomplish this step to get my sha-1:

[image]

**Update:**

I realized I already have a key cause I build and sign my project. Trying to get the SHA-1 is proving difficult with the terminal on my mac:

```
Mikes-MacBook-Air:beerPortfolio Mike$ keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey \ -keystore bp_key.keystore \ -storepass android -keypass android
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error,  -keystore is not a legal command
java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error,  -keystore is not a legal command
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.parseArgs(KeyTool.java:375)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:171)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:166)
Mikes-MacBook-Air:beerPortfolio Mike$
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850556/not-able-to-locate-keytool-on-my-mac-to-sign-my-apk-file  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292832/cannot-find-keytool-on-a-mac

Comment: Tried the command line code and I am getting an error, which is now noted above

Comment: do you have command line in Mac i didn't use Mac.

Comment: Try to remove the backslashes and the space after them from the command, that is, execute this (all in one line): keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore bp_key.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

The above command worked for me. You can change your keystore path if it is in another location.

Here is the [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#displaying_certificate_information/)

Comment: thanks, now I am just stuck with the xml part lol:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419695/android-google-maps-xml-layout-errors